# Is it possible to open a PDF file from a database-fetched Uri from Android API 28?

Tags: android, database, file, pdf, caching

I am writing a file sharing app for Android (>= API 28) and I have the following use case:

1. A user uploads a file from their local storage.
2. The user closes the app and after a while reopens it, causing the app to request the list of files to the server to populate the layout.
3. The user clicks on a file to preview it.

At this point, the most intuitive step would be, given that the app knows the file URL, just load it inside a WebView pointing to i.e. Google Docs' `https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=$myFileUrl` or any other file viewing service.

Truth is, I don't want my app to excessively cling on to an external service, so I thought at the moment of the file upload (step 1), a `content://` `Uri` is attached and stored in a database to use it in step 3.

That way, if the user hasn't renamed and moved the file he uploaded, the app could attempt to open the file locally, saving some bandwidth usage.

As @CommonsWare wrote in this [article](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html), the time the app has permission to access a `Uri` is limited; in my case it only lasts until the user closes the app. That means using  a strategy such as:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
// Getting the content:// Uri after a call to the server.
viewModel.selectedUrl.observe(this@MainActivity) { uri ->
   val newIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
   try {
      newIntent.data = Uri.parse(uri)
      newIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
      newIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
      try {
         startActivity(newIntent)
      } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
         Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      }
   // ...
}
```

Will only work if the file is uploaded and opened straight away. Is it possible to solve this issue in any way or should I just stick to the `WebView` option which does not involve any `Uri`?

**UPDATE: How is the file uploaded?**

In my `MainActivity` I have a FAB which, when clicked, triggers the following snippet:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
val fileResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        viewModel.uploadFile(result, false) // This is the Uri.
    }

fileFab.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.type = "application/*"
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
    fileResultLauncher.launch(intent)
}
```

...which after the respective `ViewModel.kt` and `Repository.kt` calls it ends up in a `Server` class with the method:

**Server.kt**

```
override fun uploadFile(uri: Uri, title: String, isSound: Boolean, callback: IFileUploadCallback) {
    Timber.d("Uploading document...")
    val inputStream = c.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
    var fileData: ByteArray? = null
    inputStream?.buffered()?.use {
        fileData = it.readBytes()
    }
    fileData?: return

    // Call to Volley
    // ...
```

Comment: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT for selecting a file gives you the possibility to take persistable uri permission. Which means read/write permission until eternity.

Comment: Adding that alongside `intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION` in my upload part will grant me opening permission, but only until the device is rebooted. That's some advancement, but it's still not permanent access. Thanks anyway!

Comment: That flag is nonsense as you cannot grant a persistable uri permission.  Further you did not get what i said. `Which means read/write permission until eternity` That means: for always. Also after reboots.

Comment: Quoting myself from the blog post: "If you used `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, or similar Storage Access Framework actions [to get your `content` `Uri`], you can try using `takePersistableUriPermissions()` on `ContentResolver` to get long-term access to the content."  How are you getting your `Uri`? You wrote "A user uploads a file from their local storage", but "upload" usually means "transfer to a server", and I do not know how you are getting a `content` `Uri` out of that.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for your quick response. Removing `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION` still only grants me permission until a reboot. You can see the upload method in my edited question.

Comment: At the moment we are not interested in any upload code. Uploading yes or no is irrelevant if you want to use an uri later. Show your code to take persistable uri permission.

Comment: `UPDATE: How is the file uploaded?` ??? Well the code below it does not upload a file. It lets the user choose a file.

Comment: You're both right.  Excuse me. I've posted an answer with what was missing and solved my issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @blackapps and @CommonsWare, I was missing the following line in my ViewModel class:

```
context.contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```

**ViewModel.kt**

```
fun uploadFile(result: ActivityResult) {
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val uri: Uri = result.data?.data!!
        context.contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.uploadFile(uri, object: Server.IFileUploadCallback {
                override fun onSuccess(fileUrl: String, content: String) {
                    uploadedFileUrl.postValue(RecyclerViewItem.Document(fileUrl, content, uri))
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `So, at the moment of uploading (just before calling Volley in the Server class), the snippet must look like:` No. No good. You should take persistable permission directly in onActivityResult and before you call uploadFile(). And you do not have to call uploadFile() to make the uri usable later.

Comment: Updated answer. Thanks! Feel free to write your own too if needed.